# “Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup” with no apparent reason

Tags: compilation-error

I get this error upon compile.

I know this kind of question reoccurs a lot. But I tried to rule out several cases: checked that the curly braces in aux file are closed. No strange symbols in tex file.

And what is also different is that after I do clean and recompile it compiles successfully. And suddenly after I write some things, it happens again.

So the error file is :

```
./forarxiv.aux:142: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.142 c
       tion*.4}\protected@file@percent }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

./forarxiv.aux:142: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.142 ction*.4}
           \protected@file@percent }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./forarxiv.aux:142: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.142 ction*.4}\protected@file@percent }

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

the last lines in the aux file:

```
\abx@aux@refcontextdefaultsdone
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{alon1994random}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{chapman2018expander}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{conlon2017hypergraph}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{dinur2007pcp}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{hoory2006expander}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{kaufman2013high}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{kaufman2016high}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{lubotzky1988ramanujan}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{reingold2002entropy}{anyt/global//global/global}
\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext{0}{sipser1994expander}{anyt/global//global/global}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{5}{Concluding Remarks}}{14}{section.5}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\tocsubsection {}{5.1}{Acknowledgements}}{14}{subsection.5.1}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{}{References}}{14}{section*.4}\protected@file@percent }
```

The error was on the last line.

But I don't think it is really problematic as it stays also in case of successful compilation.

My permeable

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=alphabetic
]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\addbibresource{/Users/eyalkarni/Dropbox/mybibilo.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.

\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\lemref[1]{\ref{lem:#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\subsecref[1]{\ref{subsec:#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand\defref[1]{\ref{def:#1}}}
\RS@ifundefined{subsecref}
  {\newref{subsec}{name = \RSsectxt}}
  {}
\RS@ifundefined{thmref}
  {\def\RSthmtxt{theorem~}\newref{thm}{name = \RSthmtxt}}
  {}
\RS@ifundefined{lemref}
  {\def\RSlemtxt{lemma~}\newref{lem}{name = \RSlemtxt}}
  {}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{fac*}{\protect\factname}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem*}{\protect\remarkname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{\protect\definitionname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{\protect\lemmaname}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{\protect\claimname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{\protect\factname}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\protect\corollaryname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newref{definition}{name=Definition~,Name=Definition~,names=Definitions~,Names=Definitions~}
\newref{claim}{name=Claim~,Name=Claim~,names=Claims~,Names=Claims~}
\newref{theorem}{name=Theorem~,Name=Theorem~,names=Theorems~,Names=Theorems~}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
```

The document is even longer. What can it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Since your document is using resources we do not have access to, we can only ask you to make a copy and then try to reduce it into something self contained you can post here that others can test as is. Right now anybodys guess.

Comment: First thing to do is removing `pdfsync` which is obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: I use it to synchronize the doc with skim. Thanks @daleif .

Comment: the first thing is always to delete the aux file and as egreg says you do not need pdfsync (synctex has been built in for many years), also are you sure you are using latin9 encoding, not utf-8?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed both things(utf8 and pdfsync). pdfsync was indeed redundant. Lets see if it happens again. When I do clean and recompile it always works.

Comment: OK, I did a test. deleted everything that was inside begin{document} and end{document} (didn't do clean). It got compiled but the compiled document contained "ction*4". So, assuming only the aux file has this effect, I will attach it.

Comment: "ction*.4" is in the error and is part of the last line of aux file - {section*.4} . Maybe  it doesn't like the *?

Comment: `ction*.4` looks like a `hyperref` bookmark.  `hyperref` is usually supposed to be (one of) the last package(s) called, and you are loading a lot of packages after it.  That may not be the cause of the problem, but should be fixed.